# How can I change permission for an Azure Web App, so I can actually upload files via FTP to it?

Tags: .net-core, ftp, azure-web-app-service, kudu

How can I change permission for a Web App, so I can actually upload files via FTP to it?

What is it I need to change in order to have permissions to upload via FTP?

I have a running site that runs ASP.Net Core. Everything works.

For debugging purposes on a weird js issue, I need to be able to edit a few js files directly on the site via FTP.

When I connect via FTP (with the credentials from the "publish profile") I can connect just fine and download files - I use Filezilla.

But if I try to upload anything, I get "550 Access is denied."

I have full access to Azure Portal etc for the site, incl. Kudu.

It does not matter if you can upload files via KUDU or some other thing - I specifically need FTP.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking question! Could you please check if your firewall is blocked outgoing FTP writes.
Also, make sure you're not trying to write to a read-only file. For this suggest using the Kudu Console (https://[sitename].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole) to look at your files and check their permissions (e.g. using 'attrib' command).

For more information about KUDU, please refer to this [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)

Refer to this document link might be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp#get-ftp-connection-information

Try checking the ftp link which is provided by  deployment center, For this Go to your web app, click Get publish profile,  choose the Publish URL under tag <publishProfile profileName="your-webapp"